# Operando con matrices. IndexOutOfBoundsException. Función equisuma recursiva en Java

Tags: java, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, matrices

necesito algo de ayuda. Quiero crear una función equisuma usando recursividad. La matriz debe ser NxN con N potencia de 2 y se considera equisuma si los elementos de las 4 submatrices que la componen suman lo mismo y a la vez cada submatriz es también equisuma. El caso base es que todas las matrices 2x2 se consideran equisuma.

Mi problema es que mi código resuelve las matrices con tamaño 4x4 o 2x2 sin problemas, pero al querer meterle una matriz 8x8 me da el error que menciono en el título. Os dejo aquí mi código y espero vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
package problema2;

public class Equisuma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer N = 8;
        int matriz[][] = new int[N][N];
        // matriz[0][0] = 1;
        // matriz[0][1] = 2;
        // matriz[1][0] = 3;
        // matriz[1][1] = 0;
        //
        // matriz[0][2] = 4;
        // matriz[0][3] = 1;
        // matriz[1][2] = 0;
        // matriz[1][3] = 1;
        //
        // matriz[2][0] = 3;
        // matriz[2][1] = 0;
        // matriz[3][0] = 0;
        // matriz[3][1] = 3;
        //
        // matriz[2][2] = 1;
        // matriz[2][3] = 1;
        // matriz[3][2] = 2;
        // matriz[3][3] = 2;

        matriz[0][0] = 1;
        matriz[0][1] = 1;
        matriz[0][2] = 1;
        matriz[0][3] = 1;
        matriz[0][4] = 1;
        matriz[0][5] = 1;
        matriz[0][6] = 1;
        matriz[0][7] = 1;

        matriz[1][0] = 1;
        matriz[1][1] = 1;
        matriz[1][2] = 1;
        matriz[1][3] = 1;
        matriz[1][4] = 1;
        matriz[1][5] = 1;
        matriz[1][6] = 1;
        matriz[1][7] = 1;

        matriz[2][0] = 1;
        matriz[2][1] = 1;
        matriz[2][2] = 1;
        matriz[2][3] = 1;
        matriz[2][4] = 1;
        matriz[2][5] = 1;
        matriz[2][6] = 1;
        matriz[2][7] = 1;

        matriz[3][0] = 1;
        matriz[3][1] = 1;
        matriz[3][2] = 1;
        matriz[3][3] = 1;
        matriz[3][4] = 1;
        matriz[3][5] = 1;
        matriz[3][6] = 1;
        matriz[3][7] = 1;

        matriz[4][0] = 1;
        matriz[4][1] = 1;
        matriz[4][2] = 1;
        matriz[4][3] = 1;
        matriz[4][4] = 1;
        matriz[4][5] = 1;
        matriz[4][6] = 1;
        matriz[4][7] = 1;

        matriz[5][0] = 1;
        matriz[5][1] = 1;
        matriz[5][2] = 1;
        matriz[5][3] = 1;
        matriz[5][4] = 1;
        matriz[5][5] = 1;
        matriz[5][6] = 1;
        matriz[5][7] = 1;

        matriz[6][0] = 1;
        matriz[6][1] = 1;
        matriz[6][2] = 1;
        matriz[6][3] = 1;
        matriz[6][4] = 1;
        matriz[6][5] = 1;
        matriz[6][6] = 1;
        matriz[6][7] = 1;

        matriz[7][0] = 1;
        matriz[7][1] = 1;
        matriz[7][2] = 1;
        matriz[7][3] = 1;
        matriz[7][4] = 1;
        matriz[7][5] = 1;
        matriz[7][6] = 1;
        matriz[7][7] = 1;

        System.out.println(equisuma(matriz, 0, 0, matriz.length));

    }

    private static Integer equisuma(int[][] matriz, Integer i, Integer j, Integer tamaño) {
        int result = 0;

        if (tamaño == 2) {
            result = matriz[i][j] + matriz[i][j + 1] + matriz[i + 1][j] + matriz[i + 1][j + 1];
        } else {
            Integer subTamaño = tamaño / 2;
            Integer subMatriz = matriz.length / 2;
            int result1 = equisuma(matriz, i, j, subTamaño);
            int result2 = equisuma(matriz, i, j + subMatriz, subTamaño);
            int result3 = equisuma(matriz, i + subMatriz, j, subTamaño);
            int result4 = equisuma(matriz, i + subMatriz, j + subMatriz, subTamaño);

            if (result1 == result2 && result1 == result3 && result1 == result4) {
                result = result1 + result2 + result3 + result4;
            } else {
                result = -1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: matriz.length / 2; esto que numero devuelve? todo me suena raro ahi...

Comment: devuelve el tamaño de la matriz/2. Lo uso para ir dividiendo el tamaño en cada iteración hasta llegar al caso base

Comment: Sugerencia: para este tipo de preguntas, es importante incluir el stack trace que recibes con la excepción, asi como indicar cual línea es la que produce el error (el stack trace incluye esta información).

Comment: Pero matriz no mide siempre lo mismo? preguntaba que numero va pasando en esa variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es el siguiente

```
Integer subMatriz = matriz.length / 2; 
int result3 = equisuma(matriz, i + subMatriz, j, subTamaño);
```

Siempre mandas el mismo objeto matriz con 8 de longitud por eso si funciona con 4 y 2

la primera iteración valdría 4 en la segunda 8 y es lo que provoca el IndexOutOFBounds exception

Te falta enviar la longitud de la matriz para que sea recursivo totalmente, para que en el primer caso diga 8 en el segundo 4 y en el último 2, pudiendo así enviar un caso de 16 sin problemas, por lo que agregaría un tamanioMatriz en vez de subMatriz.

Creo que debería funcionarte con esto:

```
Integer subMatriz = subTamaño;
```

O por que le vuelves a hacer el matriz.length?

Dejó el código que me funcionó a mí más limpio.

```
   private static Integer equisuma(int[][] matriz, Integer i, Integer j, Integer tamaño) {
    int result = 0;

    if (tamaño == 2) {
        result = matriz[i][j] + matriz[i][j + 1] + matriz[i + 1][j] + matriz[i + 1][j + 1];
    } else {
        Integer subTamaño = tamaño / 2;
        int result1 = equisuma(matriz, i, j, subTamaño);
        int result2 = equisuma(matriz, i, j + subTamaño, subTamaño);
        int result3 = equisuma(matriz, i + subTamaño, j, subTamaño);
        int result4 = equisuma(matriz, i + subTamaño, j + subTamaño, subTamaño);

        if (result1 == result2 && result1 == result3 && result1 == result4) {
            result = result1 + result2 + result3 + result4;
        } else {
            result = -1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Probado con matrices de hasta 16392 elementos. Más de eso me tronó el heap space

Comment: Dios, no me había dado cuenta de ese fallo, tienes razón estaba todo el rato pasando el mismo objeto sin llegar a reducirlo. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Si te funcionó puedes marcar la pregunta como respondida por favor. gracias.